# Blender crashing when I open preferences

Tags: error

I'm running on EndeavourOS 6.6.4 kernel, gnome 45.2 with radeon 7800xt.  rocp/hip is the lastest version, everything is newly updated.  My GPU, including hip/rocm works for everything else....  Stable Diffusion, gaming, hashcat, etc...  When I open blender it loads and runs fine until I go into the edit menu > preferences and try to chose a gpu at which point the whole thing hangs, and a few seconds later gives an option to quit now or wait. I've tried this with 3.3.14, 4.0.3 and 4.0.2 including one version I removed and forget the version number.... 3.6something.  I've tried running it from the terminal and no errors are reported on termination.  I'm not sure what to look at.

Running "blender --factory-startup --debug-all resulted in the following:

https://pastebin.com/VYSP8y2P

Comment: 3.3.14 doesn't exist and 4.0.3 is a beta version. 3.3.12 is the latest 3.3 LTS version and 4.02 the latest released version. I assume the version you've deleted is 3.6.5 LTS which is the last version before the graphics requirements were changed with version 4. That being said, there are no Blender developers here, nor does anyone here have any association with the Blender Foundation. If you suspect a bug, read [this](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Process/Bug_Reports) and report it accordingly.

Comment: 3.3.14 does exist, it's listed right on the daily builds page.  The point I was making mainly was that I've tried a number of versions starting with the current stable version so I wasn't sure it was a bug.  Thank you tho, you're right... still a good direction to go.  I'll jump over there in just a moment and get something posted.

Comment: The daily builds pages are not release versions. [This](https://www.blender.org/download/lts/3-3/) is the release page for 3.3 LTS which I checked before posting my comment.

Comment: My apologies and thank you.  Didn't mean to be argumentative and I appreciate the info.  It was late and I wasn't paying attention to myself.  I've pulled everything, reinstalled from flatpack and will re-attack everything correctly via the report a bug option (if needed).

Comment: No problem. Thanks for the update. Good luck!